# cannot run spyder (requires pyQT5 5.5+)

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder

I'm trying to run spyder, but I get the following message:

```
RuntimeError: Please check Spyder installation requirements:
PyQt5 5.5+ is required (found v5.3.2).
```

I'm new to python, and I've been installing package with both pip and pip3. I don't know if this has created some kinds of conflict, but I don't seem to be able to update PyQt5 past version 5.3.2.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I thought I had the most recent version of PyQt5. I installed it literally minutes before trying to run spyder.

Comment: If you want an easy way to get Spyder consistent with all other packages, an easy way is to [download and install the Anaconda installation of Python](https://www.anaconda.com/download/).

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We warn newbies to *not* use `pip` everywhere we can (e.g. [here](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/installation.html#installing-with-pip-experts-only) and [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases/tag/v3.3.1)). So, having you admitted that, please download and install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download). It's a win/win for everybody: you, because you'll get Spyder up and running in 15 minutes; and us, because we don't need to put more time explaining why is that `pip` is failing (which in your case is probably because you're using Python 3.4).

Comment: thanks, it works using anaconda.